# Duplicating default behavior of Unix sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, locale

Linux sort uses en_US.UTF-8 by default.

I'm trying to find a Locale and Collator that will duplicate the way that Unix(Linux) sort works by default.

Does anyone have any ideas?

- Trying to implement strcoll_l.c in glibc doesn't seem like much fun.
- RuleBasedCollator isn't speaking to me.)

Thanks much.

```
sl73caeapp03:~ $ cat f

a

A

b

B

sl73caeapp03:~ $ sort f # how to duplicate this behavior?

a

A

b

B

sl73caeapp03:~ $ LC_ALL=C sort f # not this behavior

A

B

a

b
```

-dreamer

Comment: "Linux sort uses en_US.UTF-8 by default." <-- no. It uses the defined locale in `LC_ALL` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Locale.US`?

```
String[] test = { "A", "a", "B", "b" };
Collator order = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
Arrays.sort(test, order);
for (String s : test)
  System.out.println(s);
```